# Split Strings Into Rows For The Whole Google Worksheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script to help me split strings from Column A - Column E into rows. How can I modify this script so that it can also manipulate all my other strings in the rest of the worksheet? My worksheet extends all the way to Column CG.

From: [This is the data input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyXlo.png)
To: [I would like the intended result to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thhUT.png)

Here's a link to the [sample worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qaLTduNXf-CalpEiZufwdHPPO2mzmYuri6GeACpF_n0/edit?usp=sharing)

Below is the script that I would like to modify.

```js
const result = range =>
  range.flatMap(([a, ...v]) => {
    const { vv, len } = v.reduce((o, c) => {
      const t = c.split(",");
      o.vv.push(t);
      o.len = o.len < t.length ? t.length : o.len;
      return o;
    }, { vv: [], len: 0 });
    const temp = vv.map(e => e.concat(Array(len - e.length).fill("")));
    return temp[0].map((_, c) => [a, ...temp.map(r => r[c])]);
  });
```

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I've created a new question as suggested. Is this question ok or should I change the question?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand your question, when you provide the sample input and output situations you expect, it will help users think of the solution.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike I've edited the question. Is this clearer?

Comment: Are you looking *only* for a script solution? Or are you open to a formula solution? At a glance, I believe a single array formula can produce the results you want. But in the interest of efficiency, I don't want to invest time into it if you are specifically and only wanting a script solution (which, it appears, another contributor is working on with you).

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it seems that the column "F" is different from the logic for your sample `This is the data input` and `I would like the intended result to be like this`. How about this?

Comment: In your sample Spreadsheet, the column "F" of the sheet `Intended Result` is the same logic with the column "A"?

Comment: Sorry, I've put in the wrong screenshot. I've edited it. I would like to achieve the result from "Intended Result" Sheet. 

Sorry I wasn't very clear on the questions. For columns that have single text, I would like it to copy, while those with strings to split.

Comment: @ErikTyler I would like to work on a script solution. I've tried using the array formula but it cannot manipulate data in other columns. I want to eventually automate my work when more data is added later on. Thank you for your time anyway.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that the logic for the columns "A" to "E" and the columns "F" to the last column is the same. By this, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I understood that the column "F" is the number value. By this, I think that an error occurs at `c.split()`. The reason for your issue is this. And, when I saw your sample Spreadsheet and your expected output situation, it seems that the logic for retrieving the column "A" is the same as the column "F". In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

```js
const result = range =>
  range.flatMap(([a, ...v]) => {
    const { vv, len } = v.reduce((o, c) => {
      const t = typeof c != "string" ? c.toString().split(",") : c.split(",");
      o.vv.push(t);
      o.len = o.len < t.length ? t.length : o.len;
      return o;
    }, { vv: [], len: 0 });
    const temp = vv.map(e => e.concat(Array(len - e.length).fill("")));
    return temp[0].map((_, c) => [a, ...temp.map(r => r[c].trim())]);
  });
```

- In this modification, the same logic as your current script is used. So, when you use this script, please put the formulas of `=RESULT(Data!A2:E)` and `=RESULT(Data!F2:I)` to the cells "A1" and "F1", respectively. By this, your expected result is obtained.

#### Modified script 2:

When do you want to achieve your expected goal by one script, how about the following script?

```js
const result = range =>
  range.flatMap(([a, ...v]) => {
    const { vv, len } = v.reduce((o, c) => {
      const t = typeof c != "string" ? c.toString().split(",") : c.split(",");
      o.vv.push(t);
      o.len = o.len < t.length ? t.length : o.len;
      return o;
    }, { vv: [], len: 0 });
    const temp = vv.map(e => e.concat(Array(len - e.length).fill("")));
    return temp[0].map((_, c) => [a, ...temp.map(r => r[c].trim())]);
  });

const sample = values => {
  const { v1, v2 } = values.reduce((o, [a, b, c, d, e, f, ...v]) => {
    o.v1.push([a, b, c, d, e]);
    o.v2.push([f, ...v]);
    return o;
  }, { v1: [], v2: [] });
  const t = result(v2);
  return result(v1).map((r, i) => [...r, ...t[i]]);
}
```

- In this script, please put a formula of `=sample(Data!A2:I)` to a cell. By this, your expected result can be obtained with your sample Spreadsheet.

#### Result:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

##### From:

[image]

##### To:

[image]

#### Note:

- In this script, your sample Spreadsheet is used. So when your actual Spreadsheet is different from your sample one, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Thanks. You are right. When applied to the sample spreadsheet, it works but when I apply it to my work, it is not applicable. If we ignore the column F to have the same logic as column A, is it possible for us to have a script that's similar to original script posted but the function can be extended to the entire worksheet, instead of limited to only Column E?

Comment: @Phronimos Thank you for replying. First, I apologize that my answer cannot be used for your all Spreadsheet. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. If your actual Spreadsheet is different from your sample Spreadsheet, that is a different situation. It is required to think of the solution as the other situation. And also, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the detail of your current issue from your replying. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Please do not apologize. You have been a great help thus far and I REALLY appreciate your help. Maybe I don't explain well. Let me create a new question with a new example.

Comment: Thank you. I have done resolved this question. I've also created a new question which I'd tagged you. I'm so so sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: @Phronimos Thank you for your response. I will check your new question.